# setting up a new ip address to my server and use it in docker

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I want to set up two container with two specific Public IP. So I buy another IP from my Datacenter and I set up my new Ip address (now I have 2 Ip addresses 46.102.138.124 (main),12.102.134.224) in my server and then I check it with ping in my devices and everything is okay.
after I create a docker compose file to check the ip assigning with port:

```
version: '3'
services:
  container1:
    image: nginx
    networks:
      my_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.2
    ports:
      - 46.102.138.124:80:80

  container2:
    image: nginx
    networks:
      my_network:
        ipv4_address: 172.20.0.3
    ports:
      - 12.102.134.224:80:80

networks:
  my_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.20.0.0/16
          gateway: 172.20.0.1
```

but when I use `docker exec -it container2 bash`

then use `curl jsonip.com`

the response is: `46.102.138.124 (main IP)`

but I want to use 12.102.134.224.

How can I setting up my docker-compose or my server to use it in my point?

Note: I check these questions but It didn't help me:

[How to assign static public IP to a docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34688906/how-to-assign-static-public-ip-to-a-docker-container)

[Docker assign a public IP for single container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68934416/docker-assign-a-public-ip-for-single-container)